# Poetry download packages from artifactory

Tags: python, artifactory, python-poetry

I am trying to use poetry inplace of pip to download libraries from my org's artifactory. It seems Poetry only downloads from PyPI which is a big NO for me. Can I please have specific steps on how I can have poetry download from artifactory instead using an API key if possible?

I tried following the steps in the documentation but could not understand how to set it up using an API key.I tried using poetry source add artifactory but that did not work. I am not sure if I am missing something or this is something the admin needs to setup.

Comment: Have you seen the docs page for configuring repositories? https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/

Comment: @Brian61354270 yes, but I would like to use an API key if possible instead of a password.

Comment: I also tried to follow the steps but I got an error that say "Poetry configuration is invalid. data.source[0].url must be uri.

Comment: What commands did you run? Can you provide them as formatted text in the question body? What is the URL of the artifactory server's simple repository? How does the "API token" work? Does it use HTTP basic auth, or is it part of the URL, or what?

Comment: So to connect to artifactory we use API Keys for pip. I would like a similar solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Poetry libraries using the [JFrog CLI](https://docs.jfrog-applications.jfrog.io/jfrog-applications/jfrog-cli) in 3 steps:

Step 1: [Configure JFrog CLI](https://docs.jfrog-applications.jfrog.io/jfrog-applications/jfrog-cli/configurations/jfrog-platform-configuration)

```
jf c add
```

Step 2: [Configure Poetry project](https://docs.jfrog-applications.jfrog.io/jfrog-applications/jfrog-cli/cli-for-jfrog-artifactory#building-python-packages) by selecting the repository from your Artifactory server:

```
jf poetry-config
```

Step 3: [Install the project](https://docs.jfrog-applications.jfrog.io/jfrog-applications/jfrog-cli/cli-for-jfrog-artifactory#installing-python-packages)

```
jf poetry install
```

Comment: So this will not work because installing anything requires admin privileges. I need a solution where I can point to artifactory which is accessible to everyone

Comment: Why are you saying that it needs admin privileges? Read permissions on the repository should be enough

Comment: Ohh sorry, I meant installing the Jfrog CLI

Comment: This command just downloads the JFrog CLI binary: `curl -fL https://getcli.jfrog.io/v2-jf | sh`. You can run it then with `./jf`.